# Customize Css button links color

Tags: css

I'm creating clickable CSS buttons for my website and want a green button with a white text. But my default link color (blue) is overriding everything and making the buttons with a green background but underlined blue link. What do I need to change?

```
.td-post-content a {
    color: #2200CC;
    text-decoration: underline;

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button a:link {
    color: white;
}

<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="td-post-content button" href="https://www.expatkings.com/join">Join Now</a></p>
```

I except the td-post-content links to be blue and underlined while the button links should be green with white text.

Comment: Please, add your HTML.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. Showing CSS without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, is largely pointless. That being said, you most likely have a typical _specificity_ problem. If that keyword doesn’t mean anything to you yet, please go read up on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your problem - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just add all css pseudo classes that work with "a" tag:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

```css
.button,
.button:link,
.button:visited,
.button:hover,
.button:active{
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" >Name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important. This will override the standard link color.

```css
.button{
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

:link works for elements with a href attribute that has not yet been visited.
If you wish to style all states of the link, use the following:

```
.button a {
    color: white;
}
```